# How can I get my custom news collection on frontend in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, custom-admin-grid, custom-grid, frontend-model

I had created a custom module for the news grid and form in Magento admin. I need to create custom pages with news collection on my custom news list page and a custom news detail page. How could I get the collection on frontend in magento 1.9?

I had created the custom admin grid please check the attached screenshot for the same.
[image]

This is my custom news frontend page.
[image]

Here is my custom layout file:

> **app/design/frontend/MyCustom/Theme/layout/news.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<news_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="news/news" name="news" template="custom/news/news.phtml" />
    </reference>
</news_index_index>
</layout>
```

Here is my Block file:

> **app/code/local/Custom/News/Block/News.php**

```
<?php class Custom_News_Block_News extends Mage_Core_Block_Template { 
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $news = Mage::getModel('news/news')->getNews();
    $this->setNews($news);
}

protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    parent::_prepareLayout();

    $toolbar = $this->getToolbarBlock();

    // called prepare sortable parameters
    $news = $this->getNews();

    // use sortable parameters
    if ($orders = $this->getAvailableOrders()) {
        $toolbar->setAvailableOrders($orders);
    }
    if ($sort = $this->getSortBy()) {
        $toolbar->setDefaultOrder($sort);
    }
    if ($dir = $this->getDefaultDirection()) {
        $toolbar->setDefaultDirection($dir);
    }
    $toolbar->setNews($news);

    $this->setChild('toolbar', $toolbar);
    $this->getNews()->load();
    return $this;
}

protected function _getNewsCollection()
{
    if (is_null($this->_newsCollection)) {
        $newsCollection = Mage::getModel('news/news')->getNewsCollection();
        $newsCollection
        ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('news/news')->getProductAttributes())
        ->addMinimalPrice()
        ->addFinalPrice()
        ->addTaxPercents();

        Mage::getSingleton('news/news_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($newsCollection);
        Mage::getSingleton('news/news_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($newsCollection);
        $this->_newsCollection = $newsCollection;

    }
    return $this->_newsCollection;
}

public function getDefaultDirection(){
    return 'asc';
}
public function getAvailableOrders(){
    return array('created_time'=> 'Created Time','update_time'=>'Updated Time','id'=>'ID');
}
public function getSortBy(){
    return 'id';
}
public function getToolbarBlock()
{
    $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('news/toolbar', microtime());
    return $block;
}
public function getMode()
{
    return $this->getChild('toolbar')->getCurrentMode();
}

public function getToolbarHtml()
{
    return $this->getChildHtml('toolbar');
} }
```

Here is my template file to get news list:

> **app/design/frontend/MyCustom/Theme/template/custom/news/list.phtml**

```
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?> 
<?php $newsCollection = $this->getNewsCollection(); ?>
<div class="custom-news">
    <h1><?php echo $this->__('My News Collection') ?></h1>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml(); ?>
<?php if($collection->getSize()): ?>

<?php if($this->getMode() == 'list'){ ?>
<table class="custom-news-table" id="custom_news">
    <col width="1" />
    <col width="1" />
    <col />
    <col width="1" />
    <col width="1" />
    <col width="1" />
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo $this->__('ID #') ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->__('Title') ?></th>
            <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('Created') ?></span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php $_odd = ''; ?>
        <?php foreach ($news as $_obj): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $_obj->getId() ?></td>
            <td><span class="nobr"><?php echo $_obj->getTitle(); ?></span></td>
            <td><?php echo $this->formatDate($_obj->getCreatedTime()) ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('custom_news');</script>
<?php }else{ ?>
    <!-- List Mode HTML Here -->
<?php } ?>
<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml(); ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <p><?php echo $this->__('The News collection is empty.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Please provide the solution to get the custom collection on the frontend with list and detail pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my method and got the custom collection.

Removed:

```
protected function _getNewsCollection()
{
    if (is_null($this->_newsCollection)) {
        $newsCollection = Mage::getModel('news/news')->getNewsCollection();
        $newsCollection
        ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('news/news')->getProductAttributes())
        ->addMinimalPrice()
        ->addFinalPrice()
        ->addTaxPercents();

        Mage::getSingleton('news/news_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($newsCollection);
        Mage::getSingleton('news/news_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($newsCollection);
        $this->_newsCollection = $newsCollection;

    }
    return $this->_newsCollection;
}
```

Replaced:

```
public function getCollection()
{
    $newsCollection = Mage::getModel('news/news')->getCollection();
    $newsCollection->prepareForList($this->getCurrentPage());
    return $newsCollection;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call below code instead

Remove:

```
 <?php $newsCollection = $this->getNewsCollection(); ?>
```

Replace :

```
  <?php $newsCollection = $this->_getNewsCollection(); ?>
```

Comment: Hii @gaurang I tried your solution but it didn't work. My Template is not generated on frontend. Please check the attached updated screenshot of frontend.

Comment: call url news/index/index not custom_news

Comment: The _news/index/index_ takes me to the `404 page`. The url should run with `custom_news` only, as I had mentioned the front router name in my module's config.xml file.

Comment: check your logs

Comment: Hello @gaurang, I had checked my logs and it shows this error: `"Error in file: "/home/ubuntu/magento1943/app/code/local/Custom/News/sql/news_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php" - SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'custom_news' already exists"`

Comment: If you have a server please provide me details on gaurangpd93@gmail.com   once leave details please let me know here as a comment. Trust me i here to help.

Comment: Sorry @gaurang I don't have a server. I had created the module in my local system.

Comment: Than sent a module in email. and also which magento version you are using.

Comment: Hii @gaurang, thanks for taking the time to contribute an answer. I got my custom collection on frontend by changing my block method. I had posted it in the answer.

Comment: @MOHAMMEDUBEDSHAIKH Great!!!!! keep trying is the key to success..